# C# - How can stop recursive function?

Tags: c#

I want to replace all the word that start via `@` with another word, here is my code:

```
    public string SemiFinalText { get; set; }
    public string FinalText { get; set; }

    //sample text : "aaaa bbbb @cccc dddd @eee fff g"
    public string GetProperText(string text)
    {

        if (text.Contains('@'))
        {
            int index = text.IndexOf('@');
            string restText = text.Substring(index);
            var indexLast = restText.IndexOf(' ');
            var oldName = text.Substring(index, indexLast);
            string restText2 = text.Substring( index + indexLast);
            SemiFinalText += text.Substring(0, index + indexLast).Replace(oldName, "@New");

            if (restText2.Contains('@'))
            {
                GetProperText(restText2);
            }

            FinalText = SemiFinalText + restText2;

            return FinalText;
        }
        else
        {
            return text;
        }
    }
```

When `return FinalText;` is executed I want to stop recursive function. How can fix it?

> Maybe another approach is better than recursive function. If you know another way please give an answer to me.

Comment: For your sample input of "aaaa bbbb [at]cccc dddd [at]eee fff g" what is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: I want to replace all word that start with [at] with another specific word.

Comment: @user3748973 you want exlusive to be recursive

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx). If you're not familiar with the powerful pattern-matching abilities of Regular Expressions, I can provide a little more detail.

Comment: Of course, please explain about it.

Comment: As degant says, you don't need a recursion here. The problem with your recursion is, that you are not using the return value of `GetProperText`. You should make the recursive call like `resttext2 = GetProperText(restText2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a recursive solution for this problem. You have a string containing a number of words (separated by spaces) and you want to replace the ones starting with an '@' with another string. Modifying your solution to have a simple method that splits based on spaces, replaces all words starting with @ and then combines them once again.

**Using Linq:**

```
string text = "aaaa bbbb @cccc dddd @eee fff g";
FinalText = GetProperText(text, "New");

public string GetProperText(string text, string replacewith)
{
    text = string.Join(" ", text.Split(' ').Select(x => x.StartsWith("@") ? replacewith: x));
    return text;
}
```

Output: aaaa bbbb New dddd New fff g

**Using Regex:**

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("@([^ @])*");
string result = rgx.Replace(text, replaceword);
```

Comment: If we have string like this : `aaa bbb.@ccc ddd` it doesn't work. do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Do you want this @ccc also to be replaced?

Answer (score 1):

Solution with Regular Expressions:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"@\w+";
        var r = new Regex(pattern);
        Console.WriteLine(r.Replace("ABC @ABC ABC @DEF klm.@bhsh", "BOOM!"));
    }
}
```

This does not rely on space character being the delimiter, any non-word (letters and numbers) can be used to separate the 'words'. This example outputs:

> ABC BOOM! ABC BOOM! klm.BOOM!

You can test it out here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rZyjjg

If you're new to Regex: [.NET Introduction to Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here also the proper way to **do it recursively** for anyone interested. I think your stopping condition was actually oke, but you should concatenate the outcome of the recursive function call to the already processed text. Also I think that using global variables in a recursive function defeats its purpose a little bit.

That being said I think that using RegEx from one of the supplied answer is better and faster.

The recursive code:

```
    //sample text : "aaaa bbbb @cccc dddd @eee fff g"
    public string GetProperText(string text)
    { 
        if (text.Contains('@'))
        {
            int index = text.IndexOf('@');            //Index of first occuring '@'
            var indexLast = text.IndexOf(' ',index);  //Index of first ' ' after '@'

            var oldName = text.Substring(index, indexLast);     //Old Name
            string processedText = text.Substring(0, index + indexLast).Replace(oldName, "New");    //String with new name
            string restText = text.Substring(indexLast);   //Rest Text

            if (text.Contains('@'))
            {
                //Here the outcome of the function is pasted on the allready processed text part.
                text = processedText + GetProperText(restText);
            }

            return text;
        }
        else
        {
            return text;
        }
    }
```